# VS Code displaying error with AWS SAM template.yml

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml, aws-sam

I have a `template.yml` for an AWS SAM deployment, but VS Code keeps showing the error below. `sam validate` shows no errors, and the deployment works fine. Other AWS policies, such as `DynamoDBCrudPolicy`, don't have this issue.

Is VS Code wrong or is there an actual formatting error?

[image: template error]

[image: vs code error explanation]

Comment: vs code is wrong.  `sam validate` should be useful to you.

Comment: @petey I mentioned the use of `sam validate` and it shows no problem, I opened an issue on GitHub and it seems to be a valid issue with `sam.schema.json`. I'll post my own response to explain what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discovered that `sam.schema.json` doesn't mention the `DyanmoDBWritePolicy`, leading to the error in VS Code. The issue has been brought up on [GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-vscode/issues/2018).
Just adding the following snippet to line 105509 of `sam.schema.json` should fix it momentarily, it did for me.

```
"DynamoDBWritePolicy": {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/AWS::Serverless::Function.TableSAMPT"
},
```